# Is Oracle OpenAsync etc... not a truly async method?

Tags: c#, oracle, asynchronous, odp.net

I have an Oracle database that I am accessing through ODP.NET

This is my demo code

```
public static async Task<Field[][]> ReadAsync(string ExtractSql)
{
    var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"].ConnectionString;
    List<Field[]> ret = new List<Field[]>();
    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connStr))
    {
        await conn.OpenAsync();
    }
    return ret.ToArray();
}
```

This code does **not** behave as async, the UI is completely **blocked** for seconds.
If I simply replace

```
await Task.Delay(10000); //conn.OpenAsync();
```

all works fine as expected.
Can I conclude that this is a **bug** in **ODP.NET**, is there a github repo or where can I report it or am I missing something trivial in C# async?

Is there anyone else using .NET for Oracle and experiencing a similar issue for async methods?

**Please note**

Of course I've added the code inside to open the command and read the data and the issue persists, here I'm showing *the minimal amount of code that is sufficient to detect the problem*. E.g. I have a firewall that can block the connection and in that case it times out, therefore the only "open" command can be **enough** to make the app **stuck**, if the db part is **not** async.

Comment: ODP.NET doesn't implement any of the `Async`-variant methods. The base classes have implementations of those methods that call the non-async variants and wrap the result with `Task.FromResult` (or uses a cached `Task` instance).

Comment: All async method are "synchronous" until they hit their first `await`. So yes there will be a portion of time where the thread is blocked.

Comment: Those methods aren't declared on the type. Basic reflection using `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` won't retrieve those methods.  Also, ILSpy.

Comment: @JohnWu And yet if a method proports to be asynchronous, the synchronous portion before the task is returned should be *very quick*, else it's fair to consider it a bug in that method.

Comment: @Servy "quick" and "async" are largely unrelated; what it mainly shouldn't do is do IO work synchronously; as long as it is just burning CPU, it can take as long as it likes and not violate any async assertions

Comment: @Guilio it is a common problem that not all ADO.NET providers implement all the APIs in truly async ways, meaning it is falling back to async-over-sync; it is hard to say whether a particular provider does this without knowing the exact version and having it locally - to be honest, to really know you need to look at the IL of the assembly. But yes, it has happened many times

Comment: @MarcGravell If a method doesn't return very quickly then *it's not asynchronous*. It might use the `async` keyword, but *it's not actually asynchronous* at that point.  If the method is going to run for a long time synchronously, it shouldn't claim to be asynchronous, else callers expecting it to be asynchronous, such as in this case, will not work properly.

Comment: @Giulio: I'm afraid I wouldn't be able to write an answer that fulfils your entire request. `Task.Run` sounds like a possibility but it has its own considerations and I would not be the right person to advise using it. I will say, though, that using `Task.Run` to *hide* the issue is a dangerous way to think about it. Anyway, I welcome an answer from someone else with more practical experience in this area.

Comment: @Giulio using Task.Run doesn't improve async-over-sync, and can contribute to pool exhauation,so: no

Comment: @Giulio it being implemented in the base isn't enough to be conclusive on that - often the public API is constant and there are protected implementation APIs; to be sure kinda needs the IL, not just the declaration

Comment: @Giulio I'm taking about the general case; I haven't checked the current source of ADO.NET, because that is already tying us into implementation details and specific versions, but to clarify what I mean: something doesn't need to override a public method to provide an API; it is not uncommon to override protected methods that have sufficient effects, without ever changing/overriding the public API. If it doesn't work that way in this case is interesting but not definitive other than "in this case"

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to @madreflection for the comments. I'm really happy to delete my answer and accept an answer from him, as I kindly asked.

Anyway, now it is clear by looking at Visual Studio intellisense that those async methods are not there but they are symply inherited from the generic `System.Data.Common.DbConnection`.

I should have also understood it at the first method that is not returning a `Task` or a `Task<bool>`, i.e. from the following line

```
OracleDataReader DR = (OracleDataReader) await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
```

where I was forced to add an unexpected cast (now I understand why).

I'm going to wrap the API in a `Task.Run` because I can't block my UI.

See below the screenshot with the mouse over the `OpenAsync`.

[image]

From the [doc you can read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbconnection.openasync?view=netcore-3.1)

> This is the asynchronous version of Open(). Providers should override with an appropriate implementation
> The default implementation invokes the synchronous Open() call and returns a completed task.

My person opinion is that the default implementation is doing the wrong/misleading thing, I would have rather preferred an exception "not implemented" thrown instead.